# What does this function do in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Can someone in tell me in detail what each line does of this function? Also, I do not know what the 'rangefilt' does. The code below is called when an image path is sent through via a GUI.

```
function [imC]=training(imPath)
im=imread(imPath);
x = 75;
y = 75;
reSim=imresize(im,[x,y]);
    textureim=rangefilt(rgb2gray(reSim));
    p=cat(3,reSim,textureim);
    xi=[1:1:x]';
    mi=repmat(xi, [1 y]);
    yj=[1:1:y];
mj=repmat(yj,[x 1]);
    mp=cat(3,mi,mj);
    fp=cat(3,p,mp);
    [pox poy poz]=size(fp);
    pon=pox*poy;
    vecim = reshape(fp,pon,poz);
    [temp imC]=kmeans(double(vecim),5);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Though someone already answered, I would like to urge you to at least try to figure out as many lines as possible by yourself. Display of that kind of effort is kind of a minimum for a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [imC]=training(imPath)
% //read in the image
im=imread(imPath);

% //Resize the image to be 75x75
x = 75;
y = 75;
reSim=imresize(im,[x,y]);

% // use rangefilt on a grayscale version
% //rangefilt returns (max-min) for each pixel of a 3x3 neighborhood
textureim=rangefilt(rgb2gray(reSim));

% //reshape them into two bands of p
p=cat(3,reSim,textureim);

% //These 4 lines are like meshgrid, create a vector, then repmat it into an image
xi=[1:1:x]'; % //'
mi=repmat(xi, [1 y]);
yj=[1:1:y];
mj=repmat(yj,[x 1]);

% // concatenate along third dimension (so we have another 2 band image)
mp=cat(3,mi,mj);

% //now we should have 4 bands, resim,textureim,mi,mj
fp=cat(3,p,mp);

% //get the size in x,y,z
[pox poy poz]=size(fp);

% //calculate the number of pixels in each band
pon=pox*poy;

% //reshape it to poz vectors of length pox*poy
vecim = reshape(fp,pon,poz);

% //run kmeans on the data which will cluster based on intensity, texture and position
[temp imC]=kmeans(double(vecim),5);
```

Comment: I like this answer. Once you feel confident enough, these kinds of questions are a good chance to teach new users to ask better questions (As I tried to do in the comment above). Hopefully that improves both their questions and their user experience.

Comment: Can you also explain this one please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520417/what-is-this-function-in-matlab